# ActionScript don't load HTML resources with HTMLLoader

Tags: html, xml, actionscript-3, dom, air

I'm currently downloading website via an ActionScript HTMLLoader to later have access to the DOM to get some information out of the page.

The problem is: each resource that is linked on the page (images, stylesheets, javascript) is also loaded which takes some additional time. I don't really need those resources, because only the plain HTML/DOM is interesting.

Is there any way to disable loading of linked resources? At first I tried using an URLLoader and parse the result as XML, but when the website isn't valid this doesn't work. I also didn't find a library that validates/parses a given HTML-string into valid XML.

I'm using Adobe AIR on desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps convoluted, but you could load the file with URLLoader, convert it to a string, use regex to remove links to the external resources you don't want, and then load the result into the HTMLLoader.